# How to calculate cumulative stock returns from an array of tuples in F#

Tags: arrays, f#, tuples, sequence, stock

I am trying to calculate the cumulative return of a weekly stock return time-series from an array of tuples - in which the first element is a `DateTime` object and the second the corresponding weekly return `float` - and plot it. I have however been unsuccessful in my quest. Here is a sample of my code:

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data"
#r "nuget: Plotly.NET, 4.0.0"
open System
open System.IO
open FSharp.Data
open Plotly.NET

let [<Literal>] sampleFileFullPath = "file_containing_returns.csv"
type stockData = CsvProvider<sampleFileFullPath>
let stockDataCSV = stockData.GetSample()

let calcReturn (pv : float, fv : float) = (fv / pv) - 1.0

let returns (s : stockData) (path : string) =
    let dateTimeFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    let sequence = 
        s.Rows
        |> Seq.map(fun x -> System.DateTime.Parse(x.Date), calcReturn(float x.AdjClose, float x.Open))
    let array =
        sequence
        |> Seq.toArray |> Array.map snd
   printfn "%A" array
```

As you can see above, I have tried to extract the second element of the `tuple` (stock returns). While I then managed to obtain the cumulative sum of returns over the length of the time series, I have been unable to preserve the corresponding `DateTime`. Removing the last pipe operation would make the function yield the following output:

```
[|(01/01/2000 00:00:00, 0.2368421053); (08/01/2000 00:00:00, 0.1973684211); 
  (15/01/2000 00:00:00, 0.07142857143); (22/01/2000 00:00:00, 0.2597402597);
  (29/01/2000 00:00:00, 0.09756097561); (05/02/2000 00:00:00, 0.156626506); 
  (12/02/2000 00:00:00, 0.1666666667); (19/02/2000 00:00:00, 0.1666666667); 
  (26/02/2000 00:00:00, 0.01030927835); (04/03/2000 00:00:00, 0.1894736842);
...|]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**

The (working) sample data looks like this:

```
Date, Open , High , Low , Close , AdjClose , Volume 
01/01/2000,0.94,1.00,0.85,0.89,0.76,3055203200.00
08/01/2000,0.91,0.91,0.77,0.90,0.76,3345742400.00
15/01/2000,0.90,1.08,0.90,0.99,0.84,3383878400.00
22/01/2000,0.97,1.02,0.90,0.91,0.77,2068673600.00
29/01/2000,0.90,0.98,0.84,0.96,0.82,2384424000.00
05/02/2000,0.96,1.05,0.95,0.97,0.83,1664308800.00
12/02/2000,0.98,1.07,0.97,0.99,0.84,1754468800.00
19/02/2000,0.98,1.06,0.95,0.99,0.84,1520971200.00
26/02/2000,0.98,1.18,0.97,1.14,0.97,2408918400.00
04/03/2000,1.13,1.15,1.06,1.12,0.95,1280126400.00
11/03/2000,1.09,1.13,1.02,1.12,0.95,1859289600.00
18/03/2000,1.10,1.34,1.09,1.24,1.05,2306292800.00
25/03/2000,1.23,1.29,1.12,1.21,1.03,1541019200.00
01/04/2000,1.21,1.25,1.04,1.18,1.00,1948620800.00
08/04/2000,1.18,1.19,0.94,1.00,0.85,2892668800.00
15/04/2000,0.98,1.16,0.97,1.06,0.90,2042756800.00
22/04/2000,1.03,1.15,1.02,1.11,0.94,1778358400.00
29/04/2000,1.11,1.13,0.99,1.01,0.86,1636017600.00
06/05/2000,1.00,1.02,0.88,0.96,0.82,1853790400.00
13/05/2000,0.96,0.97,0.83,0.84,0.71,2631921600.00
20/05/2000,0.84,0.84,0.74,0.77,0.66,2539454400.00
27/05/2000,0.78,0.89,0.72,0.83,0.70,2843254400.00
```

From this dataset, I take only the `Date`, `Open` and `AdjClose` columns. After computing simple returns (via the `CalcReturn` function), I am left with the `sequence`, which is then transformed into the `array` that the function is priting.

The output should look like this (assuming `first` week return is 23%, `second` week return is 17% and `third` week return is 12%, for instance):

```
[|(01/01/2000 00:00:00, 0.23); (08/01/2000 00:00:00, 0.40);
(15/01/2000 00:00:00, 0.52);...|]
```

Again, the goal is to plot the cumulative return over the course of time.
Hope this makes the issue clearer!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, can you show a sample expected output?

Comment: You're dropping out the date, so yeah, the date is not there. Please post what you want the final data to look like. It would also help to make the input file accessible, or else just create some sample data.

Comment: The sample data you added is not comma delimited, does CsvProvider parse that? (I haven't tried). It would be best to modify your example further, just feed CsvProvider the string (and fix up the data with commas, if needed). A complete working example that can be pasted directly into a script is going to make answering this easier.

Answer (score 0):

F# provides a family of functions called [`scan`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#scan) that are good for computing running totals. The challenge, as you point out, is to keep the associated date with each total. I think the simplest way is like this:

```ml
open System

let input =
    [
        DateOnly(2000, 1, 1), 0.23
        DateOnly(2000, 1, 8), 0.17
        DateOnly(2000, 1, 15), 0.12
    ]

input
    |> Seq.scan (fun (_, acc) (date, value) ->
        date, acc + value) (DateOnly.MinValue, 0.0)
    |> Seq.skip 1   // skip initial value of 0.0
    |> printfn "%A"
```

Output is:

```
seq [(1/1/2000, 0.23); (1/8/2000, 0.4); (1/15/2000, 0.52)]
```

For clarity, I've used `DateOnly` instead of `DateTime` and avoided the CSV and date formatting issues that I think you already have a good handle on.